# "созданных" или "создаваемых"?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Спорим...
Как правильно спросить:
"А в последующих **создаваемых** Вами картинах Вы не планировали его снимать?"
или
"А в последующих **созданных** Вами картинах Вы не планировали его снимать?"

Comment: @yara, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 3):

"Созданных", если речь идёт о прошлом и эти картины уже отсняты (тогда это ссылка на картины, которые уже "созданы"). Вы его не сняли - интересно, а планировали снова снять его или нет?

"Создаваемых", если речь идёт о картинах, которые в данный момент снимаются, планируются к съёмкам (идёт досъёмочная работа по "созданию") или это в широком смысле картины, время от времени "создаваемые" режиссером в силу его профессии. Например, возможна такая ситуация. Идут съёмки, а задающий этот вопрос узнал, что его знакомый актёр в них не участвует, хотя когда-то были разговоры, что режиссёр собирался его снимать, памятуя прежнее успешное с ним сотрудничество. Отсюда вопрос: вы его не планировали в своих картинах снимать впредь или собирались-таки снять не в этой, а в более поздней из "последующих" картин (из тех, что создаёте как мастер детективного жанра - "создаваемых" вами)?

Таким образом, ваш спор разрешим только в случае, если вопрос не абстрактный и известна реальная ситуация.

**P.S.**

Почему здесь не идёт речи о будущем.

Здесь "последующие" - все картины, которые могли сниматься позже самой первой с участием того актёра, причём предполагаемый момент "планирования-непланирования" мог быть раньше или позже этого. Часть этих "последующих" картин может оставаться в прошлом относительно момента, в который задаётся вопрос - это "созданные" картины. Другая часть "последующих" картин может находиться в настоящем (в процессе создания) - это картины "создаваемые" на момент задания вопроса. "Последующие" и "создаваемые/созданные" привязаны к разным моментам времени в прошлом и настоящем, соответственно, причастие здесь не связано с будущим.

1. Последующие (после первой с его участием) созданные вами картины. Да, не сняли вы его больше. А тогда вы планировали его в них снимать?
2. Последующие создаваемые вами картины. Вы их с тех пор (сняв его один раз) создавали и продолжаете создавать. А тогда вы планировали его в них снимать?

Answer (score 1):

Если речь идёт о будущем времени, причастие не может присутствовать, оно не образуется от глаголов будущего времени, обычно заменяют придаточным предложением: "А в последующих  картинах, которые только собираетесь снимать,  Вы не планировали его участие?"

Или обойтись конструкцией проще: "А в будущих картинах Вы не планировали его снимать?"

"А в будущем Вы не планируете его участие в съёмках?"

Answer (score 0):

Может, так:

*"А в последующих Ваших картинах Вы не планировали его снимать" ?*

Comment: Да скорее всего так и напишем! Просто спор из-за одного слова принципиальный, второй день ругаемся) Хочется знать правильный ответ)

Comment: На мой взгляд, неправильны оба предложенных Вами варианта. Зря ругаетесь!

Comment: yara: Как правильно спросить: "А в последующих создаваемых Вами картинах..."=== Более-менее правильным был бы, по-моему, такой вопрос:
"А в последующЕМ в создаваемых Вами картинах Вы не планировали его снимать?"

Answer (score 0):

Конечно, если ничего во фразе не менять, то надо "созданных".

Но я бы написал просто и без затей: а в *других* Ваших картинах?... Скромненько и со вкусом.

Comment: Большое спасибо! Значит, я проиграл в споре, пойду в этом признаваться)